# How can I queue multiple spotify songs with their iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, spotify

I'm using the [SPTAudioStreamingController](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTAudioStreamingController.html) Class to play a track, but I can only give it one track as opposed to the Android SDK which allowed for multiple URIs. I tried to use the `queueSpotifyURI` method but this only allows me to queue one additional track. I would like to be able to queue between 3 and 5 songs.

Answer (score 1):

Put the URI's into an array and use a for-loop to loop through each element and queue each element individually.